# Group Values under a header MSSQL

Tags: asp.net, sql, listview, group-by

I want to group my record of data under different "staff_id".

My query without the GROUP BY works flawlessly by returning all desired rows in a normal table. I output it in an asp.net ListView and it looks like this like this:

```
Staff_ID   Field1   Field2   Field3   Field4   ...........
Staff_ID   Field1   Field2   Field3   Field4   ...........
Staff_ID   Field1   Field2   Field3   Field4   ...........
```

Now I am trying to make them display in an asp.net ListView group together by their id.
For example, like this:

```
Staff_ID                                              TOTALAMT
        Field1    Field2    Field3    Field4    Field5
        Field1    Field2    Field3    Field4    Field5
Staff_ID                                              TOTALAMT
        Field1    Field2    Field3    Field4    Field5
        Field1    Field2    Field3    Field4    Field5
```

Anyway to do that? I tried the GROUP BY as shown below but i get an error:

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 4

Column 'CLAIM_APPLICATION.CREATE_DATE' is invalid in the select list because 
it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Here's my query:

```
SELECT  
    '' Seq,
    '' Doc_Type,
    left(CONVERT(varchar, A.CREATE_DATE, 112),8)Post_date,
    left(CONVERT(varchar, A.CREATE_DATE, 112),8)Doc_date,
    ('S.C-'+left(CONVERT(varchar, A.CREATE_DATE, 112),6)+'-'+ A.user_id)Header, 
    ('S.Claim-'+left(CONVERT(varchar, A.CREATE_DATE, 112),6))Header_Ref,
    '' Trx_date,
    'MYR' Curr,
    '' Exh_rate,
    '' Line_no,     
    'S' CR_DB,
    '' Nega_post,
    C.GL,
    A.AMT,
    '' Loc_curr, 
    'SC-'+ A.CLINIC_SHOP Text1,     
    B.staff_id, 
    ''A,''B,''C,''D,
    'I0'Tax_code,''WBS,''E,
    A.cost_centre,
    ''F,    
    '0003' Pay_term,    
    left(CONVERT(varchar, getdate(), 112),8)Base_date  
FROM    CLAIM_APPLICATION AS A INNER JOIN
          CLAIM_USER_DETAIL AS B ON A.user_id = B.user_id INNER JOIN
                  CLAIM_TYPE AS C ON A.CLAIM_ID = C.CLAIM_ID
WHERE   (A.CLAIM_ID NOT IN (20, 21)) 
    and (CONVERT(varchar, A.CREATE_DATE, 111) >= '2011/01/01')
    and (CONVERT(varchar, A.CREATE_DATE, 111) <= '2011/04/30')
    and (A.STATUS ='A')
    -- and A.REF_NO <> 'MYSGCB'
    -- and (A.user_id <>'bkkhoo')
GROUP BY B.staff_id
ORDER BY B.name
```

Comment: Have a look at this link, it will show you exactly what to do: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810274.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `GROUP BY` in SQL Server query will not solve your problem - you need all data returned by original query. The desired grouping is not at data level but while displaying the data. Listview does support grouping - see this [multi-part article](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150712/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/010208-1.aspx) that illustrates how to do the grouping as desired by you (specifically see part titled ["Grouping By a Data Field"](https://web.archive.org/web/20210301194237/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/091708-1.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the error you are getting is because all the columns in your group by clause must be in the select clause if it's not an aggregate column.

This however will not give you your desired result. What you should do is add summary rows in your datagrid, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810274.aspx) should give you what you want.

Also look [here](http://aspalliance.com/723_Enhancing_the_DataGrid_with_Grouped_Rows_and_Subheadings.1) for a good overview of your different options.